# PHP/Laravel Google APi w/ Calendar - Response Empty

Tags: php, google-api, laravel-5.3, google-calendar-api

I am running the following code as a Laravel command...

```
$cfg = Config::get('calendar');
$client = new \Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName('Test Application');
$client->addScope(\Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR);
$client->setAuthConfig($cfg['authConfig']);
$service = new \Google_Service_Calendar($client);
$calendarList = $service->calendarList->listCalendarList();
while (true) {
    foreach ($calendarList->getItems() as $calendarListEntry) {
        echo $calendarListEntry->getSummary();
    }
    $pageToken = $calendarList->getNextPageToken();
    if ($pageToken) {
        $optParams = array('pageToken' => $pageToken);
        $calendarList = $service->calendarList->listCalendarList($optParams);
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```

Authentication is fine, everything seems to work, but I get back an empty array for `getItems()`

Not sure what I am missing. Let me know if you need more info, I am getting a response, it is always just "itemless". I have 4 test calendars on the account.

Comment: Can you try if you're getting a response using the [Try-it](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/list#try-it)?

Comment: Yes it all worked fine there, I discovered the issue, i will add an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered what the issue was. What google neglects to document is that, regardless of the fact that you can use all their test APIs in the developer console with the owner account, you must add the @web-calendar-******.iam.gserviceaccount.com and add a share it with the proper permissions to the calendar you wish to manage.

Another thing to note is that when you share it, even though you give it the proper permissions when adding the share, it will downgrade the permissions to read only. I had to alter and save it 3 times to get it to stick.